# Problems with Builder.load_string and Builder.load_file

Tags: python, kivy

I'm doing a Navigation Drawer. When use the example of documentation with "Builder.load_string" run without problem. However, if I separed in two files (.py and .kv) using "Builder.load_file" don't run. Why? Thanks!

Here example with "Builder.load_string":

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, MDList

KV = '''
# Menu item in the DrawerList list.
<ItemDrawer>:
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    on_release: self.parent.set_color_item(self)

    IconLeftWidget:
        id: icon
        icon: root.icon
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: root.text_color


<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    spacing: "8dp"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "left"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: avatar.height

        Image:
            id: avatar
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "56dp", "56dp"
            source: "data/logo/kivy-icon-256.png"

    MDLabel:
        text: "KivyMD library"
        font_style: "Button"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDLabel:
        text: "kivydevelopment@gmail.comí"
        font_style: "Caption"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    ScrollView:

        DrawerList:
            id: md_list



Screen:

    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:

            Screen:

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Navigation Drawer"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

                    Widget:


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content_drawer
'''


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass


class ItemDrawer(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()


class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
    def set_color_item(self, instance_item):
        """Called when tap on a menu item."""

        # Set the color of the icon and text for the menu item.
        for item in self.children:
            if item.text_color == self.theme_cls.primary_color:
                item.text_color = self.theme_cls.text_color
                break
        instance_item.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        print(type(Builder.load_string(KV)))
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        icons_item = {
            "folder": "My files",
            "account-multiple": "Shared with me",
            "star": "Starred",
            "history": "Recent",
            "checkbox-marked": "Shared with me",
            "upload": "Upload",
        }
        for icon_name in icons_item.keys():
            print(self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.md_list.add_widget)
            self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.md_list.add_widget(
                ItemDrawer(icon=icon_name, text=icons_item[icon_name])
            )


MainApp().run()
```

Here example with two files "Builder.load_file":

file .py:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, MDList



class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass


class ItemDrawer(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()


class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
    def set_color_item(self, instance_item):
        """Called when tap on a menu item."""

        # Set the color of the icon and text for the menu item.
        for item in self.children:
            if item.text_color == self.theme_cls.primary_color:
                item.text_color = self.theme_cls.text_color
                break
        instance_item.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        print(type(Builder.load_string(KV)))
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")

    def on_start(self):
        icons_item = {
            "folder": "My files",
            "account-multiple": "Shared with me",
            "star": "Starred",
            "history": "Recent",
            "checkbox-marked": "Shared with me",
            "upload": "Upload",
        }
        for icon_name in icons_item.keys():
            print(self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.md_list.add_widget)
            self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.md_list.add_widget(
                ItemDrawer(icon=icon_name, text=icons_item[icon_name])
            )


MainApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
# Menu item in the DrawerList list.
<ItemDrawer>:
    theme_text_color: "Custom"
    on_release: self.parent.set_color_item(self)

    IconLeftWidget:
        id: icon
        icon: root.icon
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        text_color: root.text_color


<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    spacing: "8dp"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "left"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: avatar.height

        Image:
            id: avatar
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "56dp", "56dp"
            source: "data/logo/kivy-icon-256.png"

    MDLabel:
        text: "KivyMD library"
        font_style: "Button"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDLabel:
        text: "kivydevelopment@gmail.com"
        font_style: "Caption"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    ScrollView:

        DrawerList:
            id: md_list



Screen:

    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:

            Screen:

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Navigation Drawer"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]

                    Widget:


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content_drawer
```

Comment: If you comment out the line `print(type(Builder.load_string(KV)))` in both versions, does that make any difference?